How to set Url path with router for query parameter in routes how to mention in angular?
for suppose when i start angular application it need to show like this
http://localhost:4200/?creativeId=bydefaultId
so whenever  i start app by default one id need to be set by default so my work will show that
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/creativeID?',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }, 
  {
    path:'creativeID?:id',
    component:AdPageComponent,
  }
]

for creativeId i am doing query parameter so where i am giving id so i can mention here
i was trying to get creativeId using path so by default it need to show one image where i have set id so i want to do that using creative id i have not done that much

Rewire the routes, so that you hard code the default ID on the redirect itself.
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/creativeID?creativeId=bydefaultId',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }, 
  {
    path:'creativeID',
    component:AdPageComponent,
  }
]

Then on the component, subscribe to queryParams and get the ID.
ngOnInit() {
   this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe((params: any) => {
       const defaultId = params.creativeId;
       ...
   });
}

Another way you can pass the default ID on the route params
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/creativeID/bydefaultId',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }, 
  {
    path:'creativeID/:id',
    component:AdPageComponent,
  }
]

Then on the component, subscribe to params and get the ID.
ngOnInit() {
   this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe((params: any) => {
       const defaultId = params.creativeId;
       ...
   });
}


whenever i change creative id and enter it will not change because it is in ngoninit

@rahemanali that is why we subscribe to the observable for params or queryParams, you will notice its called, try placing a console.log() inside the subscribe, you need to put the initialization code inside this callback!

okay sorry i will do green tick i am new that s why

@rahemanali no problem! I hope I solved your problem!

yes you solved my problem i try to do green tick but it is not working it only works ones?

@rahemanali yes there can only be one right answer :)

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
